# Internal server error on Intellij Cardea (132.197) startup

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-eap

I have been using the Intellij Cardea EAP (build 132.106) till yesterday with no issues.

Today, upgraded to the latest build (132.197) and got an internal server error after the update and Cardea wouldnt start up.

The `C:\dev\.IntelliJIdea13\system\log\idea.log` reports the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.IdeaServerManagerImpl$10.listSubFiles(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/intellij/openapi/components/RoamingType;)[Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.intellij.openapi.options.SchemesManagerImpl.d(SchemesManagerImpl.java:299)
        at com.intellij.openapi.options.SchemesManagerImpl.a(SchemesManagerImpl.java:129)
        at com.intellij.openapi.options.SchemesManagerImpl.loadSchemes(SchemesManagerImpl.java:111)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.c(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:901)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.initComponent(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:293)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:548)
        ... 30 more
```

It seems to indicate that a plugin might be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above error seems to indicate that it's the `Configuration Server Plugin` is at fault.

A quick workaround is to delete `.IntelliJIdea13\config\plugins\ideaServer` (effectively uninstalling the plugin) after which Cardea should start up.

Issue raised here : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113512

Update:

This issue is now fixed. The updated plugin is attached to the issue and can be installed manually. Have also uploaded the plugin zip here : http://bit.ly/18eUH62